# I would like plot EMA weekly only on TF Daily, how do i do this?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
EmaW = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", ma1, barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)

5W = barstate.islast ? EmaW5  
plot(timeframe.isdaily and show_ema_WEEKLY ? print_5:na,"Ema 5 WEEKLY", linewidth=6, color=color.new(color.gray,50))
```

I would like see on Tf Daily Ema weekly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the purpose of the `print_5` variable in your code, nor what `5W` means, but you can replace `print_5` with the value you get from the security function to plot the weekly EMA on the daily chart only:

```
//@version=5
indicator("", overlay = true)
ema5 = ta.ema(close, 5)
ema5Weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", ema5, barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)
show_ema_WEEKLY = true
plot(timeframe.isdaily and show_ema_WEEKLY ? ema5Weekly : na,"Ema 5 WEEKLY", linewidth=6, color=color.new(color.gray,50))
```

[image: Ema 5 Weekly example]

Comment: I will try your code Thx Friend